# Selenium locator only works with inspect tab open

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape names and odds for a project I am working on with Selenium 4, and just having an issue with the locator.
When I use the **driver.find_element(By.XPATH)**, the XPATH I give it only seems to work when I open the inspect window on that particular page. When I close the inspect window, it gives me an **NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:** error.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B13/C1/D50/E2/F163/'
driver.get(url)

Player1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div').text
Player2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div').text
Odds1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span').text
Odds2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/span').text
print(f'{Player1}\t{Odds1}')
print(f'{Player2}\t{Odds2}')
```

Run just the section from Player1 onwards with the inspect window open and without it open. Hopefully you'll be able to replicate the issue.

I also ran

```
try:
    if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div').text:
        print("yay")
        
except:
    print("nay")
```

and it seemed to show the same situation. The element couldn't be found without the inspect window open. [See attached image for where I got the XPATHs from.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDsCp.jpg)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add the `HTML` source for the element you're getting mentioned issue?

Comment: Not able to access the website, but opening the inspector window reformats any webpage. It could be that your element has not been loaded yet, and opening up the inspector window (because of reformating) showed you more items. To test this theory, I would add a time.sleep() after the webpage laods, then scroll down a bit and let the element locator command execute. If it does, then it's an element loading issue